# how to connect "Kovan" or "Rinkeby" from geth

Tags: go-ethereum, kovan, rinkeby

As far as I know, the default test network is "Ropsten" and you can connect to ropsten with following command.Since it is default, when you connect to testnet its "Ropsten".

```
geth --testnet
```

I would like to connect "Kovan" / "Rinkeby" test networks. What are the required parameters connecting to these test networks?

Comment: Because rinkeby does not enter ico, like eth in your normal network.
Where is it possible to sell rinkeby, in which ico?

Answer (score 17):

For rinkeby, just type `geth --rinkeby` from command prompt and you're in

Answer (score 9):

For Kovan:

```
parity --chain kovan
```

it won't be possible to connect to Rinkeby with parity, only with geth.

Rinkeby with geth:

```
geth --rinkeby
```

Comment: How to connect to Kovan with geth?

Comment: that's just not possible to do.

Comment: @Ini it's not possible because Kovan and Rinkeby were started by separate groups. That is, Kovan is Parity's project while Rinkeby is go-ethereum team's.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use either the `--chain` or `--networkid` options, depending on your client.

---

The Kovan network is only available when using the Parity client.

From the Parity `--help` output:

> --chain CHAIN                  Specify the blockchain type. CHAIN may
>   be either a
>                                    JSON chain specification file or olympic, frontier,
>                                    homestead, mainnet, morden, ropsten, classic, expanse,
>                                    testnet, kovan or dev (default: homestead).

---

The Rinkeby network is only available when using the Geth client.

From the Geth `--help` output:

> --networkid value                    Network identifier (integer,
>   1=Frontier, 2=Morden (disused), 3=Ropsten, 4=Rinkeby) (default: 1)

Answer (score 1):

geth --rinkeby --syncmode "fast" --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=1024  --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*"