# Geth --chain option?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, cli

I am trying to connect geth to a private blockchain running parity nodes and I don't know how.  Some of my research leads me to this page:
[how to connect "Kovan" or "Rinkeby" from geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21371/how-to-connect-kovan-or-rinkeby-from-geth/21373)

They mention the "--chain" option.  But I don't see that option here:
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options

Can anyone tell me what --chain is?  Can anyone tell me if that is the same as the genesis file?

Thank you.

Comment: Kovan and Rinkeby are public test network, not private ones. Concentrate opinions and suggestions to your real question (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16866/geth-not-connecting-to-private-network) and close this one.

Comment: I know that they are public test networks.  That does not change anything.  And thank you for the suggestion but I think it is always better to break questions down into little pieces.  Especially since my main question has not been answered, perhaps because it has too many pieces in it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `--chain` option for `geth`. You can build `geth` and start it at private blockchain, as follows:

1. Install [go](https://golang.org/doc/install)
2. Clone `go-ethereum` project by `git clone https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum.git`
3. Rebuild all commands by `make all`. For example `geth`
4. Test whether everything is ok. `./build/bin/geth --datadir=./dev/data0 --networkid 2  console`. At first you should create directory `./dev/data0` to save chain data. If Ok, now you have entered geth console on private blockchain.

If you want to use `genesis.json` custom some properties, as follows:

1: create a simple `genesis.json` file

```
{
    "config": {
        "chainId": 10,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    },
    "difficulty": "0x400",
    "gasLimit": "2100000",
    "alloc": {
        "e2e7f3b19889d7a3ada2afaf80b6e4e2b2f8fd35": { "balance": "30000000000000000000000" }
    }
}
```

2: then execute `geth init` command:

```
build/bin/geth --rpc --rpcport "8080" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir "./dev/data0" --port "30303" --nodiscover --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3"
--networkid 1 init ./dev/genesis.json
```

Hope it helps~

Comment: Um thank you for trying but no it doesn't help.  It doesn't relate to my question at all.  I have already installed geth, written the custom genesis file, and init-ed it.  the problem is that when I run geth with it, geth does not connect to my private blockchain that is running Parity nodes.

Comment: I'm so sorry for misunderstand your question. You can connect parity node using `geth` as follows, 1 : execute command  `parity --geth  --config node0.toml` on terminal 2 : execute command `geth attach` on other. If this terminal contains `Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!
instance: Parity//v1.6.10-stable-1a5b176-20170721/x86_64-macos/rustc1.18.0` , it's success. [image]("https://ibb.co/kzG5NQ")

Comment: The [result](https://ibb.co/kzG5NQ)

Comment: His real problem is this one https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16866/geth-not-connecting-to-private-network

Comment: @BinGoBinBin I am not trying to connect to the ipc of a geth instance with parity.  I am trying to connect a geth node to a private network.

Answer (score -1):

Edited answer as questioner wants to connect to parity nodes.

Maybe this is more useful for you? [Is "networkID" hex or decimal?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25363/is-networkid-hex-or-decimal)

Comment: These links are not related to my question.  I am asking how to connect a geth node to a private blockchain of Parity nodes.  Not how to create a network of many geth nodes.

Comment: Hi @stone.212  Apologies for misunderstanding as your question did not mention Parity. Edited answer to reflect that you are looking to connect to parity nodes

Comment: @Alan_Buxton I am not trying to connect to parity noes.  I am looking to connect to a private blockchain that happens to be running on parity nodes.  There is a big difference.